# Убрать звук обновления в .NET WebBrowser - C++

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, c++-cli

Не могу перевсти данный код с C# в C++ или C++/CLI
Цель в заголовке.

```
    const int FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS = 21;
const int SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS = 0x00000002;

[DllImport("urlmon.dll")]
[PreserveSig]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)]
static extern int CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(int FeatureEntry,
                                              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwFlags,
                                              bool fEnable);

static void DisableClickSounds()
{
    CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS,
                                SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS,
                                true);
}
```

Comment: Почему не добавили как пробовали переписать?

Comment: Так если тебе нужен нативный C++, то тебе нужно гуглить WinApi и не нужно возиться не с какими маршалами и т п...

Comment: 1. Пробовал как мог, несколько вариантов. Нативного с++ не знаю, умею только в .нет, но с++/cli и p/invoke поставили меня втупик
2. Мне нужно что угодно, главное добится поставленной задачи. Имеется браузер, он обновляется каждые 10 сек и в нем клик, клик, клик.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переписал ваш код на C++/CLI:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;



[DllImport("urlmon.dll")]
int CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(int FeatureEntry, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::U4)] int dwFlags, bool fEnable);


public ref class PInvoke abstract sealed
{
private:
literal int FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS = 21;
literal int SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS = 0x00000002;
public:
static void DisableClickSounds() {
    CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, true);
};

};
```

Вызывайте метод так

```
PInvoke::DisableClickSounds();
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, однако, жаль, код не решил проблему. При обновлении страницы в WebBrowser противный click так и остался =(

Comment: так же остался click и при навигации в браузере (тик по ссылкам).
Может быть я не там вызываю эту функцию? я пихаю ее в Form_Load

Comment: В c# этот код работает.

Comment: ВСЁ. УРА! проблема в этой строке `int CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(int ^FeatureEntry, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::U4)] int dwFlags, bool fEnable);`
ненужен управляемый интеджер

Comment: @Smirnov, да, вы правы, исправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Ну [вот же](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537168(v=vs.85).aspx) ваша функция.

Вы должны подключить

```
#include "urlmon.h"
```

и вызвать просто вот точно так же

```
CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS,
                            SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS,
                            true);
```

Как ни странно, код ничем не отличается, даже [константы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537169(v=vs.85).aspx) определены так, как надо.

Не забудьте прилинковать `urlmon.lib`.

Comment: не получается. Подключаю так
`#include "Urlmon.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "Urlmon.lib")`
вот ошибка:`1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\objidl.h(12121): error C2872: IDataObject: неоднозначный символ` если не подключать Urlmon.h то ` error C2065: FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS: необъявленный идентификатор`

Comment: @Smirnov: А если подключить `urlmon.h`, а вызов функции закомментировать?

Comment: @Smirnov: А да, может быть у вас проект на C++/CLI, и вы используете `using namespace System::Windows::Forms;` в этом файле?